# Unable to play with absolute/relative position while using Mat Cards

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

Consider this simple code:

```
<mat-card>
  <app-a></app-a>
</mat-card>
<mat-card>
  <app-b></app-b>
</mat-card>
```

ComponentA:

```
<div>
  I dont want this div behind blue blocks but in front of them
</div>
div {
  width: 320px;
  cursor: default;
  position: relative;
  background: green;
  top: 60px;
}
```

ComponentB:

```
<div *ngFor="let row of [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]" class="div"></div>
div {
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

I'm unable to make component A in front of component B.

With div instead mat-card it's working, look at this snippet:

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  background: pink;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}

.any {
  background: blue;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="absolute">
    in front of blue div
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="any"></div>
 </div>
```

Because example is much better than code, I've made a stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ysrymo

- Top (first example) is with Material Cards, green element is behind
- Bottom (second example) is same with div, green element is in front of

I want the green element to be in front of blue green while using Material Cards but after trying some things I'm still unable to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

Provide z-index in a component.

Reason : Material components build cdk-overlay which has z-index = 1000 so you need to provide z-index greater than 1000

**a.component.html**

```
<div style="z-index:1001">
  I dont want this div behind blue blocks but in front of them
</div>
```

Working link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6de5k9